# Check sql table for values in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

If I have the following data:

#### Results Table

```
.[Required]
I want one grape
I want one orange
I want one apple
I want one carrot
I want one watermelon
```

#### Fruit Table

```
.[Name]
grape
orange
apple
```

What I want to do is essentially say give me all results where users are looking for a fruit. This is all just example, I am looking at a table with roughly 1 million records and a string field of 4000+ characters. I am expecting a somewhat slow result and I know that the table could DEFINITELY be structured better, but I have no control of that. Here is the query I would essentially have, but it doesn't seem to do what I want. It gives every record. And yes, `[#Fruit]` is a temp table.

```
SELECT * FROM  [Results]
JOIN [#Fruit] ON
'%'+[Results].[Required]+'%' LIKE [#Fruit].[Name]
```

Ideally my output should be the following 3 rows:

```
I want one grape
I want one orange
I want one apple
```

Comment: you can make pivot table with result and make simplex query on this

Comment: Please fix your tags. Can't be mysql AND sql-server, right ?

Comment: @iDevlop Oops. sql-server, they were both suggested, didn't mean to click both.

Comment: I'm actually surprised it worked at all with the wildcards on the left of the LIKE, but I am not nearly as familiar with MS SQL as I am with MySQL.
Is a bare JOIN in MS SQL interpreted as an INNER JOIN (like MySQL does) or some sort of left|outer join?

Answer (score 1):

If that kind of think is doable, I would try the other way round:

```
SELECT * FROM  [Results]
JOIN [#Fruit] ON
[Results].[Required] LIKE '%'+[#Fruit].[Name]+'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This topic interests me, so I did a little bit of searching.

### Suggestion 1 : Full Text Search

I think what you are trying to do is [Full Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms142571.aspx) .

You will need Full-Text Index created on the table if it is not already there. ( [Create FULLTEXT Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx) ).

This should be faster than performing "Like".

### Suggestion 2 : Meta Data Search

Another approach I'd take is to create meta data table, and maintain the information myself when the [Result].Required values are updated(or created).

Answer (score 0):

This looks more or less doable, but I'd start from the Fruit table just for conceptual clarity.

Here's roughly how I would structure this, ignoring all performance / speed / normalization issues (note also that I've switched around the variables in the LIKE comparison):

```
SELECT f.name, r.required
FROM fruits f
JOIN results r ON r.required LIKE CONCAT('%', f.name, '%')
```

...and perhaps add a `LIMIT 10` to keep the query from wasting time while you're testing it out.

This structure will:

- give you one record per "match" (per Result row that matches a Fruit)
- exclude Result rows that don't have a Fruit
- probably be ungodly slow.

Good luck!